# has_many belongs_to not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I've spent the last 5 hours trying to figure out why this simple association won't work. It was working before. I've provided as much code as I could.

The error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: Category: SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos"  WHERE "videos"."category_id" = ?  ORDER BY Category ASC
```

Models

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos, -> { order "Category ASC" }
end
```

Routes

```
Myflix::Application.routes.draw do

  root to: "static_pages#front"

require 'sidekiq/web'
mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'


    resources :videos do
        collection do
            get :search, to: "videos#search"
        end
        resources :reviews
    end

    namespace :admin do
        resources :videos, only: [:new, :create]
        resources :payments
        resources :categories, only: [:new, :create, :index, :destroy,  :edit, :update, :show]
    end

    resources :categories


end
```

Controller

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
before_filter :require_user

def index
    @categories = Category.all
    @videos = Video.all
end

def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
    Category.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Category Deleted."
    redirect_to admin_categories_path
end

private

def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:category)
end
end
```

View:

```
%section.genre
  %header.clearfix
    %h1=@category.category
  %article.row
    -if @category.videos.any?
      -@category.videos.each do |video|
        .video.col-sm-2
          = link_to image_tag(video.small_cover_url), video
    - else
      .video.col-sm-2
         No videos in this category
```

db schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140517182911) do

 create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "category"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
 end

  create_table "videos", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "video_description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.string   "large_cover"
    t.string   "small_cover"
    t.string   "video_url"
  end

 end
```

The error is being raised at the @categories.videos.each line and I have absolutely no idea. Everything appears to be set up correctly.

Comment: "no such column: Category". Well have you try to run a rake db:migrate ?

Comment: how do I get it to look for category id in the videos table? I thought with this type of association it would automatically look for category_id in the videos table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
 class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :videos, -> { order "category_id ASC" }
 end
```

You have `category_id` column in `videos` table and not `Category` which is why you are getting error as `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: Category`

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I would argue that most often you would not want to place that order on the association, but keep it as a separate scope.  Otherwise spot on.